# Not able to deploy IdentityServer 4 code on Azure App service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, identityserver4, azure-app-service-plans

I have used dotnetcore 3.0 to develop the IdentityServer in empty Asp.net Web Application hosting.
App Service I created is dotnetcore 3.0, Windows platform.

In my dotnet core solution I created the publish output using 'dotnet publish'

It worked fine on localhost url as I consumed that url in my client application. I have only TokenPoint and from UI application I pass username/ password

[image]

[image]

Below is the logs on App service:

2020-04-02 17:41:09 NEWIDPSERVER GET / X-ARR-LOG-ID=e83b7b1e-6f40-4f67-9f0d-0f4f474e2309 443 - 112.196.168.73 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/80.0.3987.149+Safari/537.36 ARRAffinity=c450828deae8ef5774d6b51f85ad7bb411cc76cec811344524a352e00ebf3ca1 - newidpserver.azurewebsites.net 500 30 574 2913 1374 6437
2020-04-02 17:41:19 ~1NEWIDPSERVER GET /detectors type=tools&name=eventviewer&X-ARR-LOG-ID=ec15da12-ce7e-44ae-83fe-7f8f4c9c62cc 443 - 112.196.168.73 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/80.0.3987.149+Safari/537.36 ARRAffinity=c450828deae8ef5774d6b51f85ad7bb411cc76cec811344524a352e00ebf3ca1 https://newidpserver.azurewebsites.net/ newidpserver.scm.azurewebsites.net 302 0 0 1047 1590 1062

IIS Detailed Error - 500.30 - Internal Server Error

#### HTTP Error 500.30 - Internal Server Error

The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.Most likely causes:

- IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of this error depends on which module handles the request and what was happening in the worker process when this error occurred.
- IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly.
- IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.
- The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.
- The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility Feature is not installed.

Things you can try:

- Ensure that the NTFS permissions for the web.config file are correct and allow access to the Web server's machine account.
- Check the event logs to see if any additional information was logged.
- Verify the permissions for the DLL.
- Install the .NET Extensibility feature if the request is mapped to a managed handler.
- Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=66439).

Detailed Error Information:Module   AspNetCoreModuleV2Notification   ExecuteRequestHandlerHandler   aspNetCoreError Code   0x8007023e
Requested URL   https://newidpserver:80/.well-known/openid-configurationPhysical Path   D:\home\site\wwwroot\.well-known\openid-configurationLogon Method   AnonymousLogon User   Anonymous

More Information:This error means that there was a problem while processing the request. The request was received by the Web server, but during processing a fatal error occurred, causing the 500 error.

[View more information »](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=62293&IIS70Error=500,30,0x8007023e,14393)

Microsoft Knowledge Base Articles:

2020-04-02 17:42:35 NEWIDPSERVER GET /.well-known/openid-configuration X-ARR-LOG-ID=3273401b-d59d-4e79-ba95-207ca2a8273f 443 - 112.196.168.73 - - - newidpserver.azurewebsites.net 500 30 574 2923 892 0
2020-04-02T17:44:45  No new trace in the past 1 min(s).
2020-04-02T17:45:45  No new trace in the past 2 min(s).
2020-04-02T17:46:45  No new trace in the past 3 min(s).
2020-04-02T17:47:36  Welcome, you are now connected to log-streaming service. The default timeout is 2 hours. Change the timeout with the App Setting SCM_LOGSTREAM_TIMEOUT (in seconds).
2020-04-02T17:48:36  No new trace in the past 1 min(s).
2020-04-02T17:49:07
System.ApplicationException: The trace listener AzureBlobTraceListener is disabled. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The SAS URL for the cloud storage account is not specified. Use the environment variable 'DIAGNOSTICS_AZUREBLOBCONTAINERSASURL' to define it.at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.WebSites.Diagnostics.AzureBlobTraceListener.RefreshConfig()--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2020-04-02T17:49:07  PID[6956] Information Loading modules from D:\Program Files (x86)\MiddlewareModules\1.2.4\Microsoft.Azure.AppService.Middleware.Modules.dll
2020-04-02T17:49:08  PID[6956] Verbose     Detected application setting 'WEBSITE_AUTH_LOGOUT_PATH' = '/.auth/logout'
2020-04-02T17:49:08  PID[6956] Verbose     Detected application setting 'WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED' = 'False'
2020-04-02T17:49:08  PID[6956] Verbose     Detected application setting 'EASY_AUTH_CONFIG_CONTENTS' = '{"preserveUrlFragmentsForLogins":false,"endpointPath":{"apiPrefix":"/.auth","logoutPath":"/.auth/logout","LogoutCompletionPath":"/.auth/logout/complete","mobileCompatibilityEnabled":false},"allowedExternalRedirectUri":{"allowedExternalRedirectUrls":null,"AllowedExternalRedirectUriCollection":[]},"nonce":{"validateNonce":true,"nonceExpirationInterval":"00:05:00"},"token":{"stateDirectory":"D:\home\data\.auth","TokenStorePath":"D:\home\data\.auth\tokens","tokenStoreEnabled":false,"tokenStoreContainerSasUrlSettingName":null,"tokenRefreshExtensionHours":72.0},"isAuthEnabled":false,"requireHttps":true,"defaultProvider":null,"unauthenticatedClientAction":0,"authConfigDirectory":null,"hideDeprecatedSecurityIds":false,"AppTracingLevel":31,"useLegacyClaims":true,"warmupPath":null,"forwardingHeader":null,"functionsExtensionVersion":null,"cookieExpirationTime":"08:00:00","azureActiveDirectory":{"openIdIssuer":null,"clientId":null,"clientSecretSettingName":null,"clientSecretCertificateThumbprint":null,"allowedAudiences":null,"loginParameters":null,"aadBypassSingleTenancyCheck":false,"activeDirectoryAcl":null,"disableWwwAuthenticateResponse":false,"OpenIdIssuerValue":null,"OpenIdConfigurationUrl":null},"facebook":{"facebookAppId":null,"facebookAppSecretSettingName":null,"facebookScope":null,"facebookGraphApiVersion":"v3.3"},"gitHub":{"gitHubAppId":null,"gitHubAppSecretSettingName":null,"gitHubScope":null},"twitter":{"twitterConsumerKey":null,"twitterConsumerSecretSettingName":null},"google":{"googleClientId":null,"googleClientSecretSettingName":null,"googleScope":null,"allowedAudiences":null},"openIdConnectProviders":null}'
2020-04-02T17:49:08  PID[6956] Verbose     Detected application setting 'WEBSITE_CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS' = '*'
2020-04-02T17:49:08  PID[6956] Verbose     Detected application setting 'WEBSITE_CORS_SUPPORT_CREDENTIALS' = 'False'
2020-04-02T17:49:08  PID[6956] Verbose     Detected application setting 'WEBSITE_AUTH_LOGOUT_PATH' = '/.auth/logout'
2020-04-02T17:49:08  PID[6956] Verbose     Detected application setting 'WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED' = 'False'
2020-04-02T17:49:08  PID[6956] Verbose     Detected application setting 'EASY_AUTH_CONFIG_CONTENTS' = '{"preserveUrlFragmentsForLogins":false,"endpointPath":{"apiPrefix":"/.auth","logoutPath":"/.auth/logout","LogoutCompletionPath":"/.auth/logout/complete","mobileCompatibilityEnabled":false},"allowedExternalRedirectUri":{"allowedExternalRedirectUrls":null,"AllowedExternalRedirectUriCollection":[]},"nonce":{"validateNonce":true,"nonceExpirationInterval":"00:05:00"},"token":{"stateDirectory":"D:\home\data\.auth","TokenStorePath":"D:\home\data\.auth\tokens","tokenStoreEnabled":false,"tokenStoreContainerSasUrlSettingName":null,"tokenRefreshExtensionHours":72.0},"isAuthEnabled":false,"requireHttps":true,"defaultProvider":null,"unauthenticatedClientAction":0,"authConfigDirectory":null,"hideDeprecatedSecurityIds":false,"AppTracingLevel":31,"useLegacyClaims":true,"warmupPath":null,"forwardingHeader":null,"functionsExtensionVersion":null,"cookieExpirationTime":"08:00:00","azureActiveDirectory":{"openIdIssuer":null,"clientId":null,"clientSecretSettingName":null,"clientSecretCertificateThumbprint":null,"allowedAudiences":null,"loginParameters":null,"aadBypassSingleTenancyCheck":false,"activeDirectoryAcl":null,"disableWwwAuthenticateResponse":false,"OpenIdIssuerValue":null,"OpenIdConfigurationUrl":null},"facebook":{"facebookAppId":null,"facebookAppSecretSettingName":null,"facebookScope":null,"facebookGraphApiVersion":"v3.3"},"gitHub":{"gitHubAppId":null,"gitHubAppSecretSettingName":null,"gitHubScope":null},"twitter":{"twitterConsumerKey":null,"twitterConsumerSecretSettingName":null},"google":{"googleClientId":null,"googleClientSecretSettingName":null,"googleScope":null,"allowedAudiences":null},"openIdConnectProviders":null}'
2020-04-02T17:49:08  PID[6956] Verbose     Detected application setting 'WEBSITE_CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS' = '*'
2020-04-02T17:49:08  PID[6956] Verbose     Detected application setting 'WEBSITE_CORS_SUPPORT_CREDENTIALS' = 'False'
2020-04-02T17:49:08  PID[6956] Verbose     Detected application setting 'WEBSITE_AUTH_SIGNING_KEY' = '0F****'
2020-04-02T17:49:08  PID[6956] Verbose     Detected application setting 'WEBSITE_AUTH_ENCRYPTION_KEY' = 'CE****'

IIS Detailed Error - 500.0 - Internal Server Error

#### HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error

The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.Most likely causes:

- IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of this error depends on which module handles the request and what was happening in the worker process when this error occurred.
- IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly.
- IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.
- The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.
- The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility Feature is not installed.

Things you can try:

- Ensure that the NTFS permissions for the web.config file are correct and allow access to the Web server's machine account.
- Check the event logs to see if any additional information was logged.
- Verify the permissions for the DLL.
- Install the .NET Extensibility feature if the request is mapped to a managed handler.
- Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=66439).

Detailed Error Information:Module   AspNetCoreModuleV2Notification   ExecuteRequestHandlerHandler   aspNetCoreError Code   0x00000000
Requested URL   https://newidpserver:80/.well-known/openid-configurationPhysical Path   D:\home\site\wwwroot\.well-known\openid-configurationLogon Method   AnonymousLogon User   Anonymous

More Information:This error means that there was a problem while processing the request. The request was received by the Web server, but during processing a fatal error occurred, causing the 500 error.

[View more information »](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=62293&IIS70Error=500,0,0x00000000,14393)

Microsoft Knowledge Base Articles:

---

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRbOC.png): [image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeALq.png

Token on my local:

[image]ack.imgur.com/X6Ch3.png

Comment: Found this link and chanhes web.config: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59369322/net-core-3-0-and-iis-http-error-500-30-ancm-in-process-start-failure-failed

Comment: Now error log has changed:

Comment: logs in question is updated. Earlier error was  500.30, now is 500.0

Comment: Which method do you use for publishing, using Visual Studio or dotnet publish CMD ?Generally, the above errors will not appear when publishing with Visual Studio. If you use dotnet cmd to publish, I am willing to try and give you further help.

Comment: @jason yes I used cli command dotnet publish

Comment: Did you try to publish by visual studio ? If not, you can try it, and it works fine, then you code is no problem. Tks, pls try it. I will try to publish it by your way.

Comment: I saw you devlop with visual studio, I want to know which tools you use to publish? In Package Manager Console  Or VS Code ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210844/discussion-between-jason-and-dotnetavalanche).

Comment: No Success. I repaired Visual Studio and  try publish . I managed to create Publish profile and it published. Same issue persist.  Then I tried install VSCode Extension added configuration of Apps ervice in Extension and tried publish. It published but Issue Persist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can publish you webapps by vscode, if you has something with your visual studio.

Add Extensions about azure, and open your project which created by visual studio. Run it in local make sure you can open the site.

Then you can deploy you apps follow the  [document about publish app by vscode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/publish-to-azure-webapp-using-vscode?view=aspnetcore-3.1)  .I suggest you deploy apps by visual studio. I think it's easy publishing with Visual Studio.

Comment: one of the links  you shared help identify the exact issue. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/troubleshoot-azure-iis?view=aspnetcore-3.1    dotnet \home\site\wwwroot\{ASSEMBLY NAME}.dll