# HTTP Error 500.37 - ANCM Failed to Start Within Startup Time Limit

Tags: c#

[image]

I get this result after i ran the API. 
May i ask, how to fix this issue?

Comment: How long does it take for timeout to occur?  Found similar issue : https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/20194

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59369322/net-core-3-0-and-iis-http-error-500-30-ancm-in-process-start-failure-failed helped me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. close applications running on the system
2. turns out because access takes a long time
3. Webconfig upgrade startupTimeLimit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms524792(v=vs.90)

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to resolve this by:

1. Closing Visual Studio
2. Restarting my App Pool in IIS
3. Restarting Visual Studio
4. Rebuilding my app

(Just restarting IIS without the VS reset did not help).

Answer (score 0):

This error happened to me when running my site on my local machine. Restarting my PC resolved the issue. ASP.NET Core 3.1