# issue running app on IIS server, keep getting app failed to start

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

IIS 10 ASP.NET Core app failed to start

Getting error HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start when i launch the web app. In event viewer i have:

Application '/LM/W3SVC/3/ROOT' with physical root 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MarCRM_Pro' has exited from Program.Main with exit code = '1'. Please check the stderr logs for more information.

and

Application '/LM/W3SVC/3/ROOT' with physical root 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MarCRM_Pro' failed to load coreclr. Exception message:
CLR worker thread exited prematurely

The app on Visual Studio 2019 works when i run it then i publish it to a folder and copy that to the IIS server.

hopefully i can find some answer soon, i have been trying different things found by googling but so far no luck.

Comment: Can you run a report to show more about your IIS settings? https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html

Comment: What's the .net core version you using? If it is 3.1, please upgrade it to .net 5 and publish again. If it is .net 5, please check application pool if it disable 32 bit application. then rebuild the application again in visual studio and publish again.(delete the original published  application)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to find a fix to this by changing in web.config file.

In the web.config file had to change the `hostingModel="OutOfProcess"` from `"InProcess"`

Post where i was able to find this fix.
[.NET Core 3.0 and IIS: HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure: failed to load coreclr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59369322/net-core-3-0-and-iis-http-error-500-30-ancm-in-process-start-failure-failed)

Thanks for your input guys.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue today, turned out the connection string was pointing to a database that was renamed or it did not exist on the server. The second issue in connection string was that it was providing the UserID and password but still using integrated security.

So, if you are facing this issue, it *could* be related to your database connection.